# Error while executing linux command using Java

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to execute the following command using Java

```
Process acquirInterfaces = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dumpcap -D");
```

and getting error as

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "dumpcap": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Linux box where im executing this command has got installed with dumpcap which is located under (/usr/local/bin)

What is the mistake im doing, please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following line, with exact path:

```
Process acquirInterfaces = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/dumpcap -D");
```

Answer (score 4):

Then try

```
Process acquirInterfaces = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/local/bin/dumpcap -D");
```

And in case you have any problem with the slash, use File.separator:

```
Process acquirInterfaces = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(File.separator + "usr" + File.separator + "local" + File.separator + "bin" + File.separator + "dumpcap -D");
```

Comment: Why would there be any problem with the slash?

Answer (score 1):

As noted, you need to use the full name of the executable. The reason for this is that in Unix systems, searching for commands on the path is handled by the shell, not the system call itself, so when you're running a command by using a system call, you have to specify exactly where to find the program to run.

Comment: Thanks Chrylis, useful info